# Relocating an Answer to a More Specific Question

Tags: discussion, answers, answering-questions

I wrote an answer to a question, which was only tangentially related to the general concept of the question. Later I discovered that there already exists another question that my answer would addresses specifically.

Here is the question I answered: [2014 BIOS Write-Protect Screw HP Chromebook 14](https://superuser.com/questions/837870/bios-write-protect-screw-hp-chromebook-14)

...and [my_answer](https://superuser.com/a/1415795/590021)

Here is the question I discovered: [2017 How to remove BIOS Write-Protect Screw for HP Pavilion 14 Chromebook](https://superuser.com/questions/1245442/how-to-remove-bios-write-protect-screw-for-hp-pavilion-14-chromebook)

I have already received an up-vote on my answer, and don't want to delete it. Is there a way to move an answer from one question to another. Or should I post a duplicate? Should I post a link to my other answer? I would post a link in a comment, but don't have enough rep. How do I make this tidy?

#### Update------------------------

Well I guess we resolved this. Although not without some clumsiness.

We got there in the end though.

In the future should I just post the new and delete the old? Will it be noticed what I did? Or will I lose rep? I noticed like 10 rep disappeared when I deleted my question(although happily back now).

I suppose I could just put links under each to each other with explanations of the situation, until the old one gets deleted or I feel like deleting it...

...its just kind of annoying to lose rep when you have so little.

#### Update------------------------

[link to new answer location](https://superuser.com/a/1423494/590021)

rep currently at 51. you can stop up-voting now!

Comment: Are you sure your answer answers both questions? The newer question explicitly says "I have also checked a similar problem BIOS Write-Protect Screw HP Chromebook 14, **but it's not the same board type**."

Comment: exactly! both questions are for HP 14" chromebooks but the second one matches my answer. the boards are the same...it looks like he even linked the one i answered...

Comment: perhaps I will write a duplicate? I'm sure the other can get deleted later. it's about Chrubuntu, which is pretty much dead as far as i can tell

Comment: @DavidPostill how should i repost the image though? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfRSG.jpg) will this get deleted if the original post disappears?

Comment: I posted a duplicate, it looked like the image auto linked to the existing file. Hopefully it doesn't get deleted for any reason.

Comment: ok I've deleted the old answer. please upvote the new answer so I don't lose my precious few rep. here is the new, correct answer: https://superuser.com/a/1423494/590021

Comment: thanks anonymous up-voter! ...you know, I'm not even sure you need to remove [write-protect screw to install chrubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/837870/bios-write-protect-screw-hp-chromebook-14)

Comment: @kipbits - Please stop asking for votes.  If the answer is considered helpful people will upvote it.

Comment: @kipbits - If you are upset about losing reputation earned from contributions you submitted you should not delete them.  You also should not submit identical answers to multiple questions.  If you find yourself doing that, you likely found a question that is a duplicate of another question, instead of duplicate answers flag the question as a duplicate of the question you answered.